# How to assemble 2x2x1000 array from four 1000x1 arrays

Tags: matlab

We have four 771x1 arrays that we want to form a 2x2x771 array.
How to make R from H L N and P?

```
H = [1 2 3 4 5]';
L = [6 7 8 9 10]';
N = [11 12 13 14 15]';
P = [16 17 18 19 20]';
R = [1 6; 11 16];
R(:,:,2) = [2 7; 12 17];
R(:,:,3) = [3 8; 13 18];
R(:,:,4) = [4 9; 14 19];
R(:,:,5) = [5 10; 15 20];
R
```

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple:

```
R=permute(reshape([H,L,N,P]',2,2,[]),[2 1 3])
```

Comment: Yes, simple when ones brain can arrange such arrays. Thanks Mendi.